# How can I use for loop iterator as a dynamic value in random.choice() to select a random element from a list with the same name as i's value?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have a list called punch:

```
punch = ['dodges punch','catches fist','moves out of the way']
```

The code below will print 'punch':

```
def bang(atk, atkL):
    for i in atk: 
       if i in atkL:  
          print i
```

But the code below will not print a random element from punch:

```
def bang(atk, atkL):
    for i in atk: 
       if i in atkL:  
          print (random.choice(i))
```

It keeps printing one of the letters from the word punch ('p' or 'u' or 'n' or 'c' or 'h').

This code will print a random element from punch:

```
print (random.choice(punch))
```

How do I add the iterators value in the random.choice function so that a random element from punch is printed?

```
def bang(atk, atkL):
    for i in atk: 
       if i in atkL:  
          print (random.choice(i))
```

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to format code

Comment: your code is incomplete. what do you pass as arguments for `bang`? and you have 2 for loops with the same variable (`i`)... that is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. 1. Which value are you passing as `punch` to your function? 2. You already know `random.choice(punch)` generates what you desire. What is the issue then? 3. Based on your sentence *"It keeps printing one of the letters from the word punch"* means `"punch"` is a string. But the `random.choice(punch)` shows it is variable. What exactly `punch` is?

Comment: instead of variable `punch` create dictionary with `data = {"punch": [...]}` and you will have no problem to use `random.choice(data["punch"])` or `random.choice(data[i])`

Comment: Hiro, First I check to see which, if any, elements exist within both atk and atkL.  Then I want to print a random element from any list that is named the same thing as the elements that exist within both atk and atkL.  Additional code will only over complicate a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need dictionary

```
moves = {
    "punch": ['dodges punch','catches fist','moves out of the way'],
    "kick":  [ ... ],
    "jump":  [ ... ],
}
```

And then you can use `i = "punch"` to get random punch

```
random.choice(moves[i])
```

or `i = "kick"` to get random kick

```
random.choice(moves[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

punch = ['dodges punch','catches firdt','moves out of the way']

def bang(atk, atkL):
    for i in atk:
        if i in atkL:
            print(random.sample(punch,1))

bang(punch, punch)
```

Use this code, as I thought you are looking for something like random output.

But;

```
random.choice(seq)
```

Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.